# How do you index a RaggedTensor along the ragged dimension, in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ragged

I need to get values in a ragged tensor by indexing along the ragged dimension. Some indexing works (`[:, :x]`, `[:, -x:]` or `[:, x:y]`), but not direct indexing (`[:, x]`):

```py
R = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print(R[:, :2]) # RaggedTensor([[1, 2], [4, 5]])
print(R[:, 1:2]) # RaggedTensor([[2], [5]])
print(R[:, 1])  # ValueError: Cannot index into an inner ragged dimension.
```

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors) explains why this fails:

> RaggedTensors supports multidimensional indexing and slicing, with one
>   restriction: indexing into a ragged dimension is not allowed. This
>   case is problematic because the indicated value may exist in some rows
>   but not others. In such cases, it's not obvious whether we should (1)
>   raise an IndexError; (2) use a default value; or (3) skip that value
>   and return a tensor with fewer rows than we started with. Following
>   the guiding principles of Python ("In the face of ambiguity, refuse
>   the temptation to guess" ), we currently disallow this operation.

This makes sense, but how do I actually implement options 1, 2 and 3? Must I convert the ragged array into a Python array of Tensors, and manually iterate over them? Is there a more efficient solution? One that would work 100% in a TensorFlow graph, without going through the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 2D RaggedTensor, then you can get behavior (3) with:

```
def get_column_slice_v3(rt, column):
  assert column >= 0  # Negative column index not supported
  slice = rt[:, column:column+1]
  return slice.flat_values
```

And you can get behavior (1) by adding an assertion that rt.nrows() == tf.size(slice.flat_values):

```
def get_column_slice_v1(rt, column):
  assert column >= 0  # Negative column index not supported
  slice = rt[:, column:column+1]
  with tf.assert_equal(rt.nrows(), tf.size(slice.flat_values):
    return tf.identity(slice.flat_values)
```

To get behavior (2), I think the easiest way is probably to concatenate a vector of default values and then slice again:

```
def get_colum_slice_v2(rt, column, default=None):
  assert column >= 0  # Negative column index not supported
  slice = rt[:, column:column+1]
  if default is None:
    defaults = tf.zeros([slice.nrows(), 1], slice.dtype)
  ele:
    defaults = tf.fill([slice.nrows(), 1], default)
  slice_plus_default = tf.concat([rt, defaults], axis=1)
  slice2 = slice_plus_defaults[:1]
  return slice2.flat_values
```

It's possible to extend these to support higher-dimensional ragged tensors, but the logic gets a little more complicated.  Also it should be possible to extend these to support negative column indices.